# How would you morph objects to fit inside offset box of a mesh?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, transforms, instances

[image]

I am trying to distort each mesh geometry to fit within the box made by offsetting the mesh surface.

[image]
[image]

So far I have successfully been able to modify each object individually by manipulating vertex groups from the original object after the Realize Instance node.

where I am stuck is:

1. Selecting each box and its corners
2. using that data to distort the related geometry
3. the best way to distort

Keen to hear if there is a simpler way to achieve this, that still enables me to modify each object after.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello ! Not an answer but you might be interested in https://archive.blender.org/developer/D13515 or the Tissue Add-on (not Geometry Nodes)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it could be an option.